# Is this a standard library error, or mine?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

When I try to compile a program I'm working on, I get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.1/string:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘struct std::pair<trie<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, bool>’:
main.cpp:7:15:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_pair.h:127:17: error: ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = trie<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator; _T2 = bool]’ declared to take const reference, but implicit declaration would take non-const
       constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;
                 ^
```

If I'm reading the error correctly, this sounds like a problem with the standard library, although my money is still that it's my fault somehow...

If it matters, here is main.cpp (`trie.h` is a class I'm working on):

```
#include <string>
#include "trie.h"

int main()
{
    trie<std::string> t;
    t.insert("te");
    trie<std::string> u(std::move(t));

    for(auto i: u)
        ;
}
```

---

EDIT:  And here is the relevant trie code.  `trie.h`:

```
template<typename T>
class trie {
public:
    // misc. declarations
    class iterator;
    typedef T key_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef iterator const_iterator;

    // constructors
    trie(trie<T>* const = nullptr, bool = false);
    trie(const trie<T>&, trie<T>* const = nullptr);
    trie(trie<T>&&);
    template<typename InputIt> trie(InputIt, InputIt, trie<T>* const = nullptr);

    // destructor, auto-generated one is fine
    ~trie() =default;

    // ...

    // other members
    std::pair<iterator,bool> insert(const value_type&);

    // ...

private:
    std::map<typename T::value_type, std::unique_ptr<trie<T>>> children;
    trie<T>* parent;
    bool is_leaf = false;
};

#include "trie_iterator.h"

// ...

template<typename T>
std::pair<typename trie<T>::iterator,bool> trie<T>::insert(const value_type& value)
{
  bool inserted = false;
  bool at_leaf = false;
  std::stack<typename iterator::state> parents;
  trie<T>* currentNode{this};

  for(const auto& it = value.begin(); it != value.end(); ++it) {
    bool is_last = (it + 1 == value.end());
    auto childIt = currentNode->children.find(*it);
    if(childIt == currentNode->children.end()) {
      inserted = true;
      if(is_last) {
        // The sequence is new to this trie, so insert it.
        // It is the last element, so don't create a new trie.
        parents.emplace(
          currentNode,
          currentNode->children.emplace({*it, {nullptr}}).first
        );
      }
      else {
        // Create a new trie and follow it.
        std::unique_ptr<trie<T>> p(new trie<T>(currentNode));
        currentNode = currentNode->children.emplace(*it, std::move(p)).first->second;
      }
    }
    else {
      if(is_last) {
        if(childIt->second != nullptr) {
          inserted = true;
          at_leaf = true;
          childIt->second->is_leaf = true;
        }
        // Done.  Build a return value.
        // TODO
      }
      else {
        if(childIt->second == nullptr) {
          childIt->second = new trie<T>(currentNode);
          inserted = true;
        }
        currentNode = childIt->second;
      }
    }
  }
  // Build pair and return it
  return {{std::move(parents), value, at_leaf}, inserted};
}
```

I apologize for how lengthy this code is; note that **the implementation of `insert` doesn't matter; the error appears no matter what**, including with an empty `insert` body.

And here is the `trie<T>::iterator` class:

```
template<typename T>
class trie<T>::iterator {
    friend class trie<T>;
    // TODO: Either this structure or trie::parent is not needed
    struct state {
        state(const trie<T>* const node, const typename std::map<typename T::value_type, std::unique_ptr<trie<T>>>::const_iterator& node_map_it ) :
            node{node}, node_map_it{node_map_it} {}
        bool operator==(const state& other) const {
            return node == other.node && node_map_it == other.node_map_it;
        }
        const trie<T>* node;
        typename std::map<typename T::value_type, std::unique_ptr<trie<T>>>::const_iterator node_map_it;
    };
    enum class fall_to {left, right};
public:
    iterator() =default;
    iterator(trie<T>* node) {
        parents.emplace(node, node->children.cbegin());
        at_end = (parents.top().node_map_it == parents.top().node->children.cend());
        at_leaf = parents.top().node->is_leaf;
        fall_down();
    }
    ~iterator() =default;
    iterator(typename trie<T>::iterator& other) =default;
    iterator(typename trie<T>::iterator&& other) :
        parents{std::move(other.parents)},
        built{std::move(other.built)}
    {}
    iterator& operator=(typename trie<T>::iterator other) {
        swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }

    void swap(typename trie<T>::iterator& other) {
        std::swap(parents, other.parents);
        std::swap(built, other.built);
    }
    static void swap(typename trie<T>::iterator& a, typename trie<T>::iterator& b) { a.swap(b); }

    const T& operator*() const { return built; }
    const T* operator->() const { return &built; }

    void operator++() {
        if(at_leaf)
            at_leaf = false;
        else
            while(++parents.top().node_map_it == parents.top().node->children.cend())
                walk_up();
        fall_down();
    }
    void operator--() {
        if(at_leaf)
            walk_up();
        while(parents.top().node_map_it-- == parents.top().node->children.cbegin()) {
            at_leaf = parents.top().node->is_leaf;
            if(at_leaf)
                // No need to fall down.
                return;
            walk_up();
        }
        fall_down(fall_to::right);
    }

    bool operator==(const typename trie<T>::iterator& other) const {
        return parents.top() == other.parents.top() && at_end == other.at_end;
    }
    bool operator!=(const typename trie<T>::iterator& other) const { return !operator==(other); }
private:
    iterator(const std::stack<state>& parents, const T& built, bool at_end) :
        parents{parents}, built{built}, at_end{at_end} {}
    void inline fall_down(const enum fall_to fall = fall_to::left) {
        // TODO: This function could possibly be made smaller.
        trie<T>* child;
        if(at_leaf)
            return;
        while((child = parents.top().node_map_it->second.get()) != nullptr) {
            built.push_back(parents.top().node_map_it->first);
            if(fall == fall_to::left) {
                parents.emplace(child, child->children.cbegin());
                at_leaf = child->is_leaf;
                if(at_leaf)
                    return;
            }
            else // fall_to::right
                parents.emplace(child, --child->children.cend());
        }
        // One final push_back to put the final element (the one that has no
        // children) in built.
        built.push_back(parents.top().node_map_it->first);
    }
    void inline walk_up() {
        built.pop_back();
        parents.pop();
    }

    std::stack<state> parents;
    // TODO: we could switch the use of push_back and pop_back for insert and erase
    // using an end iterator, to gain some additional compatibility.
    T built;
    bool at_end;
    bool at_leaf;
};
```

Comment: seems like some problem with `trie`

Comment: Please try to create a minimal complete example that reproduces the error. Remove everything that is not relevant to the problem you are asking about. This is the only way we can reliably diagnose the problem.

Comment: Are you using a pair in trie.insert()? I guess it is what is causing the problem. Post your trie code.

Comment: @GopiKrishna, ok, but it's pretty gnarly...

Comment: If I replace trie with std::vector, then things work fine (also change t.insert to t.push_back), so the problem is definitely with `trie`

Comment: if nothing else fails, the linking will, since the constructors are not implemented

Comment: @BЈовић The constructor is implemented, I just omitted it.

Comment: The problem seems to be in `trie<T>::insert`. Please post the actual implementation, especially how you instantiated the return value.

Comment: The error is going to be in the omitted implementation, not the declarations.

Comment: The error appears no matter what the implementation is.  But ok.

Comment: Well your implementation has to return a value, and how you construct the return value is going to be key.

Comment: If not, then try doing this: `auto val = t.insert("te");` I HAVE run into issues like this in the past where a return value is not assigned, which could be a compiler issue.

Comment: It looks to me like maybe this is due to your trie class declaring a move constructor but no copy constructor. What happens if you declare an explicit copy constructor (trie(const trie&))?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe the problem is with your return statement. If you say that the implementation doesn't matter, then please post the simplest implementation that still gives you the same error, preferably one that doesn't use initializer lists to construct the return value.

Comment: The simplest implementation that gives the error is an *empty `insert` function.*  Also, @mattnewport, @Gerald, neither of your suggestions helped...

Comment: An empty insert function should give you an error that you are not returning a value.

Comment: But it doesn't!  I don't think the compiler gets that far.

Comment: I think it's something to do with the copy constructor for the trie iterator. The error is telling you that pair's implicit copy constructor would have signature pair(pair&) rather than pair(const pair&) which means that one of pair's members doesn't have a copy constructor that takes a const ref. That must be the iterator.

Comment: Okay. Then obviously something else is going on ;) Please post the iterator class.

Comment: @mattnewport you are a genius.  Adding const to the copy constructors' arguments worked perfectly.

Comment: I elaborated my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you that:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_pair.h:127:17: error: ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = trie<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator; _T2 = bool]’ declared to take const reference, but implicit declaration would take non-const
   constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;
```

In other words, the implicit copy constructor generated for pair would have signature pair(pair&) rather than pair(const pair&). According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

> **Implicitly-declared copy constructor**
>
> If no user-defined copy constructors are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare a copy constructor as an inline public member of its class. This implicitly-declared copy constructor has the form T::T(const T&) if all of the following is true:
>
> - all direct and virtual bases of T have copy constructors with references to const or to - const volatile as their first parameters
> - all non-static members of T have copy constructors with references to const or to const volatile as their first parameters
>
> Otherwise, the implicitly-declared copy constructor is T::T(T&). (Note that due to these rules, the implicitly-declared copy constructor cannot bind to a volatile lvalue argument)

Most likely your iterator is not declaring its copy constructor with iterator(const iterator&).

Comment: Perhaps the OP could replace the `= default` with an explicit implementation of the copy.  This would highlight which member it is unable to copy as `const`.  Is this reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

The clue seems to be in the part of the error message that says:

```
 ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) \
     [with _T1 = trie<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator; _T2 = bool]’
```

This suggests that your `trie` is somehow implicated (read: it is your bug, not the standard library). But without a whole lot more code, one would be hard pressed to narrow it down further for you.